# How can I launch the wp7 built-in Bing search from an application

Tags: silverlight, search, windows-phone-7, bing

I would like to be able to invoke the Bing built-in search application from my silverlight based wp7 application when the user clicks on a button in my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a SearchTask

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.searchtask(v=VS.92).aspx

```
SearchTask searchTask = new SearchTask();
searchTask.SearchQuery = "Overflow7";
searchTask.Show();
```